# Cut a row from a dataframe and paste it to another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, row, paste, cut

[image]

Hello , i got a DataFrame table let's call it RC1.It's at the top.
[image]

And i got an another table let's call it Vehicle1.I need to cut RC1 row(0) to the begining of Vehicle1 table.I write my code.
`zero_row=rc1.iloc[0,:]`

`vehicle1=pd.concat([zero_row, vehicle1]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Here is the result, it takes the zero_row as a column.I try to reshape it but failed.
I look all stackoverflow but the examples are all lists.
Thanks for everyone.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end,no one answered so I found a solution.Here it is:

```
zero_row=rc1[rc1["CUST_NO."]==0]      
vehicle1=rc1[rc1["CAR_TYPE"]==0]
vehicle1=pd.concat([zero_row, vehicle1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This time I chose the row.Then concat, it worked!! Thanks for everyone.[image]